# Can I configure LiveID in PROD environment skipping INT one?

Tags: authentication, configuration, claims-based-auth

I have a problem with the registration test LiveId account via https://login.live-int.com/

I need to get PUID user required in the LiveID integration process with SharePoint 2010.

The problem is that after submission of data to https://login.live-int.com/ I'm just returned to the same page without any notification. This also applies to newly registered users.

After asking the Microsoft support, the answer was: *“If you are trying to hit http://account.live-int.com, then this is ‘by design’. It is not accessible outside corpnet.” you should use the live site http://Live.com instead of the staging.”*

The question is, can I configure LiveID in PROD environment skipping the INT one? or INT environment is required for compliance process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't skip it. I've correctly configured Live ID authentication, created INT account and tried to login using it. I've been shown Access Denied for PUID@live.com. Bingo!